# Removing java 8 from Raspbian Jessie adds packages?

Tags: raspbian, java

I'm try to remove java 8 and for some reason a whole bunch of new packages are being added.  How do I prevent this?

```
# apt-get remove oracle-java8-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java gconf-service gconf2 gconf2-common gnome-mime-data icedtea-7-jre-jamvm libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libcanberra0 libgconf-2-4 libgconf2-4 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libice-dev
  liborbit-2-0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libsctp1 libsm-dev
  libvorbisfile3 libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev lksctp-tools openjdk-7-jdk
  openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless psmisc python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal tzdata-java
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Suggested packages:
  gconf-defaults-service libbonobo2-bin libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-pulse desktop-base libgnomevfs2-bin libice-doc
  libsm-doc libxcb-doc libxt-doc openjdk-7-demo openjdk-7-source visualvm icedtea-7-plugin sun-java6-fonts
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei ttf-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic python-doc python-tk
  python2.7-doc binfmt-support
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  oracle-java8-jdk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java gconf-service gconf2 gconf2-common gnome-mime-data icedtea-7-jre-jamvm libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libcanberra0 libgconf-2-4 libgconf2-4 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libice-dev
  liborbit-2-0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libsctp1 libsm-dev
  libvorbisfile3 libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev lksctp-tools openjdk-7-jdk
  openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless psmisc python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal tzdata-java
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
0 upgraded, 50 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 68.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 41.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: Looks like it is trying to replace it with `openjdk`, possibly because there is something on the system which depends on java...or else just because :/

Comment: @goldilocks How do I make it staup?

Comment: Dunno.  I guess you could try uninstalling `openjdk` afterward and hope it doesn't do the same thing the other way around.

Comment: Why do you want to uninstall Java 8

Comment: Found this... https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=122830 ...and it worked.

Comment: @SteveRobillard The apt-get install of java 8 and java in general is difficult to manage.  The pieces are spread out and liberally meshed back together via symbolic links.  It's hard to follow and unnecessary.  Once I've removed it, I put a single directory in /opt and a single symbolic link to the current version... so much easier.